# How do I create a function to print out the total element in a list

Tags: python, kivy

How do I print out the total element in the list out. I need a function that would print out the total element in the val_holder list and where it should be placed in the code, I will appreciate if I can get the full code implementation

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 

val_holder=[]

class LandingScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  # put whatever pos_hint value you want.          
self.btn1=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_press=self.click_b1))
self.btn2=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_press=self.click_b2))
self.btn3=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_press=self.click_b3))


            
self.add_widget(self.btn1)
self.add_widget(self.btn2)
self.add_widget(self.btn3)

     def click_b1(self, instance):
          val_holder.append('a') 
     def click_b2(self, instance):
          val_holder.append('b')
     def click_b3(self, instance):
          val_holder.append('c') 

 # I need a function to print out the total element in the val_holder list     

class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

To print all the items in the list, just do:

```
print(val_holder)
```

To find the number of elements in the list, just do:

```
print(len(val_holder))
```

Comment: I am not printing out all the items, I need a  function to print out the total items in the list

Comment: What do you mean by total element? Do you mean the total number of elements in the list?

Comment: Refresh your page, I added it to my answer

Comment: print(len(val_holder))

Comment: now the problem is this where should I place it in the code above, cause if I place it after the third button it will work for only the third button not all

Comment: you can store it as a variable, after the third button. Then, you can access the value whenever you want, even before the variable is declared

Answer (score 0):

If there is any problem with len() function, then try this code:

```
length = 0
for i in val_holder:
  length += 1

print(length)
```

Comment: @Gavin Wong if I place it after the third button on_press function will it work